# Unity игры для бота telegram

Tags: unity3d, telegram-bot

Всем привет.
Можно ли написать игру на Unity для своего игрового бота в Telegram?
Если да, то где можно узнать, как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

**Нельзя**. Игры в Telegram - это **HTML5**.

[**Games**](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#games)

> Your bot can offer users HTML5 games to play solo or to compete against each other in groups and one-on-one chats.

Не стоит обольщаться возможностью **Unity** собираться в HTML5, т.к. на самом деле это **WebGL**, с которым даже не всякий десктопный браузер совместим, не говоря уже о мобильных. В своей [документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-browsercompatibility.html) разработчики **Unity** об этом пишут:

> Note that Unity WebGL content is **not currently supported on mobile devices**. It may still work, especially on high-end devices, but many current devices are not powerful enough and don’t have enough memory to support Unity WebGL content well. For this reason, Unity WebGL shows a warning message when trying to load content on mobile browsers (which can be disabled if needed).

Там же можно посмотреть таблицу совместимости для десктопных браузеров.

Comment: В Unity можно собрать проект под html6

Comment: Если требуется HTML5, а Unity это поддерживает, то почему нет?

Comment: В версии 5.4.1f и выше можно проект на html5 можно собрать (Я в комментарии выше описку сделал)